# pyspark reduceByKey only 1 value per key

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

From multiple csv files with 150 attribute per line in average, I need to satisfy this SQL request in pyspark :

```
SELECT object_id, COUNT(*), MAX(source_id), MIN(ra), MAX(ra), MIN(decl), MAX(decl)
```

I used one map function that takes each line, filter and outputs the required fields :

```
Map Output : < object_id , Array( objectid , 1,sourceid,ra,decl] ) >
```

I used one reduce function that computes all of the required aggregated functions at once (A and B are arrays as described in the map output):

```
def generalReduce(A,B):
    myarrayRet = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    myarrayRet[0] = A[0]
    #count
    myarrayRet[1] = A[1] + B[1]
    #maxSrcId
    myarrayRet[2] = A[2] if A[2] > B[2] else B[2]
    #minRa
    myarrayRet[3] = A[3] if A[3] < B[3] else B[3]
    #maxRa
    myarrayRet[4] = A[3] if A[3] > B[3] else B[3]
    #minDecl
    myarrayRet[5] = A[4] if A[4] > B[4] else B[4]
    #maxDecl
    myarrayRet[6] = A[4] if A[4] > B[4] else B[4]
    return myarrayRet
```

Problem is , that there are some keys which only have 1 value, so the reduce phase is outputting an array of 4 positions. This let me think that the reduce function is only called if the key has more than 1 value, am I wrong ?; if not, how can I do to output a custom value if there is only one value per Key ?

Thank you.

Comment: testttttttttttt

Comment: Sorry, it was bad idented , and is my first time using the platform.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I am understanding your problem correctly. If you have a Key-Value RDD like `data` like below:

```
Map Output : < object_id , Array( objectid , 1,sourceid,ra,decl] ) >
```

And use `data.reduceByKey(generalReduce)`, your function generalReduce should be commutative and associative. That is, if you have three elements, `generalReduce(generalReduce(elem1,elem2),elem3)` should be equal to `generalReduce(elem1,generalReduce(elem2,elem3)`. In your code, the returning value of `generalReduce(elem1,elem2)` is not the same type as `elem3` so you should take that into account. In fact, I don't think your code is doing what you intend it to do.

For your second question, in the case that this is what you want to do, you could use a map for converting the values in the correct format.